# Fetch max date from multiple records

Tags: plsql

From the below two table want to fetch max date record.

```
Table: account

ID  account  date

-----------------------
1   SBI      01-10-2005

2   SBI      05-11-2014

3   AXIS     02-06-2003

4   AXIS     01-08-2015




Table : user

ID    date          user      Type

--------------------------------------

1     01-10-2005    amit        C

2     05-11-2014    rahul       D 

3     02-06-2003    raghu       C

4     01-08-2015    sumit       C



OUTPUT:

ID  account  user      date
--------------------------------

2   SBI      rahul   05-11-2014

4   AXIS     sumit   01-08-2015
```

Comment: How are the two tables linked?

Comment: i think we can use grouping method??

Comment: `select ca.id,ca.account,cf.user,ca.date  from account ca,user cf
where ca.id=cf.id
and ca.account in ('SBI','AXIS')
and cf.type='C';`

Comment: _With above query i'm unable to get a proper data_

Answer (score 0):

I assume you will need the max(date) from Account table. Let me know.

There will always be repetitive entries for each column which comes in select and group by clause to give non-unique result.

Anything in select clause which is not aggregated (max/min/avg etc.) should be added in group by clause.

1) Following will show you account, user and the max of the date.

```
select ca.account,cf.user,max(ca.date) from 
account ca,user cf 
where ca.id=cf.id 
and ca.account in ('SBI','AXIS') 
and cf.type='C'
group by ca.account,cf.user;
```

2) Following will show the max date per account.

```
  select ca.account,max(ca.date) from 
    account ca,user cf 
    where ca.id=cf.id 
    and ca.account in ('SBI','AXIS') 
    and cf.type='C'
    group by ca.account;
```

3) Following will show the user and it's max account date.

```
   select cf.user,max(ca.date) from 
        account ca,user cf 
        where ca.id=cf.id 
        and ca.account in ('SBI','AXIS') 
        and cf.type='C'
        group by cf.user;
```

Comment: it giving two output for each account

Comment: It is giving because there are 2 uses associated with account. Do you need to group only on the account names? if Yes, then try following. select ca.account,max(ca.date) from 
account ca,user cf 
where ca.id=cf.id 
and ca.account in ('SBI','AXIS') 
and cf.type='C'
group by ca.account;

Comment: with this query i'm getting proper data, but what about the other column which i want to fetch i.e llike output

Comment: Whatever columns needed against max date should be added in select and group by clause. Does this helps?

Comment: Yes but while giving other coulmn(i.e user and id) in select it gives two output of same account.

Comment: I edited the answer to clarify your comments. Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: i'm getting two row for the account AXIS while selecting id,account,user...infact i required only one row for account AXIS

Comment: AXIS has 2 users ( raghu and sumit. Id 3 and 4 respectively). That is why you get 2 rows.
Try "2) Following will show the max date per account." from the main Answer I gave. You will get 1 row.

Comment: YEs with your 2 answer i will get one row for AXIS but how to get other column in select like id,user,account..which is not happening ,once i giving this column in select again getting 2 row.

Comment: It is concept of the aggregation. If you want to run any aggregation SQL. i.e group by clause. There are 2 rules. 1) The columns in select clause should be part of group by clause. or 2) Select Columns should have aggregated function. i.e. Average, max, min etc. The moment you get another column apart from the account, you are bound to get the non-unique rows of combination of columns in select clause. So the output you are getting is correct. You need to decide where you need grouping is it only account or id. If you need grouping on both, both columns will be selected.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but how to get both column selected include grouping and output will be one row for AXIS account?